# Using the same bibliography file between different PCs

Tags: bibliographies, auxiliary-files

As you may understand from the title, I need to use the same bibliography file between different computers. The file is synchronized using dropbox, and so the path of such a file is different in each computer. I tried to do this:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{~/Dropbox/Path/To/The/Bibliography}
```

This didn't work. I would like to avoid to use different paths for each computer. Is it possible?

Comment: you can use `\bibliography{Bibliography}` and then arrange the folder is in your BIBINPUTS on the relevant machines, just as you don't put a full path to `plain.bst` or `article.cls` etc

Comment: or you can create a link on each computer, pointing on the bib file: `ln -s /path/something.bib ./something.bib`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and deeenes while you are wrinting the comment I found a partial solution (see the answer below). Thanks

Comment: @amorvincomni your document is more easily portable if you don't put paths in the file (if you do want a path you can use `~` as `\string~` in web2c based texs) a one-off customisation to put your dropbox folder in your default tex and bibtex input path and it then works for all documents

Answer (score 3):

I had partially solved the problem:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{../../../Path/To/The/Bibliography}
```

Where the number of ../ is equal to the number of folder necessary to return into the dropbox folder. As an esample if you have your bibliography file biblio.bib  and your work.tex file in the paths

```
~/FolderSync/Latex/Bilbiography/biblio.bio
~/FolderSync/Work/Math/work.txt
```

Then in your work.tex file you have to put

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{../../Latex/Bibliography/biblio}
```

I hope this could help someone!